# How do you run atom text editor on linux as sudo?

Tags: php, linux, xampp, atom-editor

I tried to run sudo linux atom with my file name as signup.php in xampp htdocs

```
sudo atom signup.php
```

And then I recieved the following error

```
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

Can someone please assist me

By using the sudo command I was expecting to open the file in atom as an elevated user it's just that when I use

```
atom signup.php
```

It works and opens up the file in the text editor only issue is that it asks for my password upon saving the file and when I enter it, it keeps on asking for it infinitely

Comment: Why would you run an edit with sudo? Run it normally on a copy of the file, then use `sudo` to copy it back to the privileged location.

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like a bad idea. Have a development environment where you can edit the code as you please, and then deploy it to the restricted area when it's ready to be used.

Comment: @Barmar so you never did `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` ? There are plenty of reasons why one would run an edit command with elevated privileges. I don't say that OPs use case is a particular good way of handling it, but I use sudo for file edits _all the time_. Why should I want to do 4 steps that take close to a minute, when i could do it in 1 step in 10 seconds?

Comment: @Malik Yeah, I admit to `sudo vi filename`. But I don't feel *good* when I do it. :)